# Later.js - Next month on same date

Tags: javascript, laterjs

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ccarns/hXPU9/

Trying to get the month option to display the same day of the next month. Current implementation returns 1st day of month.

```
later.parse.text("every 1 month");//later.parse.recur().every(1).month();
```

I understand the end days of the month are problematic - I don't mind if the users chooses the 27th or higher that would assume last day of the month.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I am finding the examples are lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next months on same date you get using `on()` method in `Month` case:

```
sched = later.parse.recur().on(startdate.getDate()).dayOfMonth();
```

So, if the start date is set to `12/17/2013` the result is:
`12/17/13 | 01/17/14 | 02/17/14 | 03/17/14 | 04/17/14 | 05/17/14 | 06/17/14 | 07/17/14 | 08/17/14 | 09/17/14 | 10/17/14 | 11/17/14 |`

And you are right: there is no much examples. I checked the code and those tests [at jsperf](http://jsperf.com/later-schedule-def)

Specific date every two months:

```
sched = later.parse.recur().on(startDate.getDate()).dayOfMonth().every(2).month();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I finally just figured that out. Now I am fighting to understand how to schedule something every 2 weeks or 2 months.  My fiddle has been updated to show progress.

Comment: The same day every 2 months? And for example each Monday every 2 weeks?

Comment: Just updated fiddle again with more notes in what I am shooting for- but...  For every 2 months if start date is 12/17/2013 I would expect 12/17/13  | 02/17/14 |  04/17/14 | etc...

Comment: I played using cron parser. This `sched = later.parse.cron('0 0 0 17 */2 *', true);` produce `01/17/14 | 03/17/14 | 05/17/14...`. Date is hardcoded but can be set.

Comment: Thanks I was trying to make it readable and not use Cron but can live with it except  12/04/13 and 01/04/13 produces the same results- I ll keep playing but thanks for the continued help!

Comment: Thanks so much @Anto_Jurkovic. The chaining worked great there except for some reason it starts on the next occurence then adds two months. On our 12/17 example above it returns 12/17 first but on this one it returns 1/17 then every 2 months. Seems like a bug but I guess I can go to the previous month and then run the schedule.   PS I have been updating my jsFiddle base as I fix/figure things out. You can see the issue there

Comment: PS I was so close - with the chainging I had the .every(2).month() in the middle of the statement instead of the end. Thanks!